# NSURLSession Show Tasks In Suspended State?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I know that invoking `getTasksWithCompletionHandler` on an NSURLSession:

> Asynchronously calls a completion callback with all outstanding data,
>   upload, and download tasks in a session.

However, from experimentation, I can see the data, upload, and download task arrays returned by the method;

```
func getTasksWithCompletionHandler(_ completionHandler: ([NSURLSessionDataTask], [NSURLSessionUploadTask], [NSURLSessionDownloadTask]) -> Void)
```

are in fact only show executing tasks. I.e., tasks which have received `resume()`.

This can be seen by copy pasting this code in a Playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
let url = NSURL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    NSLog("Done")
})

session.getAllTasksWithCompletionHandler { (tasks:[NSURLSessionTask]) -> Void in
    NSLog("\(tasks)")
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.finishExecution()
}

//task.resume()
```

Note that `getTasksWithCompletionHandler` and `getAllTasksWithCompletionHandler` - the latter released in iOS 9 - seem to only differ in the signature of the completion closure.

Also, somewhat tantalisingly, `NSURLSessionTask` has a `state` property `NSURLSessionTaskState` that gives us `Running`, `Suspended`, `Canceling`, `Completed`.

Is there a way to access the list of non-executing tasks; those that have been aded to the `NSURLSession` yet have not resumed?

Comment: Apple : "Each task starts out in a suspended state. After your app calls resume on the task, it begins downloading the specified resource. "

You have to call resume() method once you have created the task objects.
By default tasks  are in suspended state.

Comment: How can I access that array of suspended tasks?

Comment: In URLSession you will get the getallTasks method which givess all suspended task array.